# Navbar no ocupa la pantalla entera en mobile(Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leerme. Tengo una consulta. Estoy realizando mi portafolio y estoy utilizando bootstrap. Tengo conocimientos, pero quizás no lo suficiente, pero cada día se aprende algo nuevo.

Yo deseo que cuando la pantalla se encuentre en dispositivos móviles, y quiera visualizar la barra de navegación presionando el icono de hamburguesa, me ocupe toda la pantalla; sabemos que bootstrap hace que sólo ocupe cierta porción y no se ve completamente bien a la vista.

Les dejo el código acá:

Aquí el documento HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold" href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/Logotipo-Portafolio.png" width="50" height="50">
                <span>
                    Daby-dat/> </span>
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarPrincipal"
                aria-controls="navbarPrincipal" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu-collapse" id="navbarPrincipal">

                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="section-hero" id="home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-5">
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img class=" img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" src="/assets/img/8.JPG" alt="Presentation image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-5">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h1 class="display-4 my-name font-weight-bold">I'm David Gómez</h1>
                        <p class="lead font-weight-bold my-desc">
                            Developer
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hoja de estilos CSS:

```
/* Navbar */

.navbar {
    background: #000000 !important;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    width: 100%;
}



/* Hero Section */

.section-hero {
    padding: 200px 0px;
    background: url(/assets/img/hero.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/img/hero.png);
    height: 941px;
}
```

Comment: Solo para aclarar lo que quieres, ¿Quieres algo como esta seccion "External content"? -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#external-content

Comment: Hola @Excorpion realmente no. La barra de navegación mostrará los links de la página, ya sea anclas o una redirección. Cuando entra en el tamaño de pantalla móvil, sólo ocupa una porción y no la pantalla de la web entera.

Comment: entonces, algo mas como esto [ejemplo](https://bootstrap-menu.com/demos/offcanvas-collapse.html) (mira la version mobile) , pero que no ocupe TODA la pantalla. Y la mostraras sobre el contenido, o en su propia seccion?

Comment: Exactamente algo así. Al intentar aplicar los cambios mencionado por el autor, no funciona la hamburguesa y no muestra los links(en mi caso).

Comment: Actualiza a como lo tienes ahora para darle una mirada.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Intenta solucionarlo con **media queries**

2.- Preguntate a partir de que tamaño quiero que mi nav abarque toda mi pantalla

3.- Una vez que elijas la respuesta le cambias el tamaño a tu nav ejemplo:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #navbarPrincipal{
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Estamos diciendo que cuando la pantalla tenga un tamaño de 600px, el nav abarcara todo el alto de tu pantalla.

Te dejo un enlace para que profundices mas en el tema de media queries

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Esto es algo que ya había probado previamente y que no me funcionó.

Comment: Hay alguna manera de poder ver tu proyecto en produccion, para poder inspeccionar y realizar las pruebas correspondientes, ya que solo estariamos adivinando sobre tu proyecto